# Is there any logic to find if there is at least one true in a row

Tags: r

Is there any logic to find if there is at least one true in  a row

```
EmployeeID <- c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109)
Created <- c("2020-06-19","2020-06-20","2020-06-21","2020-06-24","2020-06-25",
             "2020-06-28","2020-06-28","2020-06-23","2020-06-24")
happy <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
active <- c("false", "false", " "," ", "false", "True"," ", "false", "false")
sad <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
energitic <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
df <- data.frame(EmployeeID, Created, happy, active, sad, energitic)
```

Expected output

```
101
106
108
```

I am trying to extract the employeeId who has atleast One true in Each row.

Comment: In the dataset there is no 106 or 108 i.e. the EmployeeID showed in the example is 101, 102 and 104

Comment: Also, based on the input, all the IDs showed have alt least one true per row

Comment: I have corrected my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using `base R` with `rowSums` and `rowsum`.  Create a logical matrix (`df[-(1:2)] == 'True'`) based on the occurence of 'True' values, on the columns other than 'EmployeeID', 'Created', get the `rowSums`, do a group by `sum` with `rowsum` with 'EmployeeID' on the logical vector and check if there are any values greater than 0, and return the row names of the matrix ('m1')

```
m1 <- rowsum(+(rowSums(df[-(1:2)] == 'True') > 0), df$EmployeeID) > 0
row.names(m1)[which(m1)]
#[1] "101" "106" "108"
```

`rowsum` is not needed if the 'EmployeeID' are unique i.e. no duplicates

```
df$EmployeeID[(rowSums(df[-(1:2)] == 'True') > 0)]
#[1] 101 106 108
```

---

If we want to use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(Flag = "True" %in% c_across(happy:energitic)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Is there any way further to create a new column with True and false by using mutate function

Comment: @priya you meant the rows where the EmployeeID are 101, 106, 108 are all TRUE and others FALSE, right?

Comment: Yes , I want to create a new column where the EmployeeID are 101, 106, 108 are all TRUE and others FALSE

Comment: @priya updated the post

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the employeeID with at least one "True" in each row

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(-EmployeeID, -Created), any_vars( . == "True")) %>% 
  select(EmployeeID) %>% 
  extract2(1)
```

Comment: Getting following error; could not find function "extract2"

Comment: This function is from magrittr, you have to add "library(magrittr)". I will edit the answer